# Custom commands path error in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I tried to make some bash custom commands in ubuntu 12.04, so i used `mkdir bin` to make a personal bin in my home directory and `nano test` to add the file and put this bash script in:

`#!/bash/bin
echo "totally works"`

And then `chmod 775 test`.

So here is where the problem comes in, whenever I do `test`, there is no error and no output. But when i do `./test`, it returns `totally works`. I checked `.profile` and the script said:

`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi`

And please don't say i didn't log-out and log back in, because i did. And still, same thing, no error and no output when i do `test`.

I also tried checking the `$PATH` with `echo $PATH`, and I got this:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

So I am stumped on this one, please and thank you for any help at all.

Comment: Don't call it `test`. There's already a command called `test`. Move the script you wrote into your newly created `bin` directory. You can do it in one step: `mv test ~/bin/another_name`

Comment: As Eric said, don't call it `test`.  Also, to verify that your bin directory is where you think it is, run `ls "$HOME/bin"`.

Comment: Ok, I tried `ls $HOME/bin` and it said `test`, then I renamed `test` to `test5` and then to `pooperdooper` both with the same results: `bash: pooperdooper: command not found` and `bash: test5: command not found`

Comment: OK, in that case, `~/.profile` _should_ have put `$HOME/bin` in the `PATH`.  Try `source ~/.profile; echo "$PATH"` and see if it gets added to the path.  If it doesn't, then there appears to be a problem with the PATH getting overwritten by some other statement somewhere in the initialization process.

Comment: I think he should put an export command before the PATH variable

Comment: `.profile` is read when you start a new shell. Have you tried starting a new shell? If you have and still get the same error, you can try changing `PATH=` to `export PATH=`, though PATH really should already be marked for export. If *that* doesn't work, try `bash -x ~/.profile` and see if your PATH logic runs at all. Keep an eye out for other commands that may overwrite the PATH after the lines you posted.

Comment: That worked! Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

your hashbang line is incorrect

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: Good and correct point.  If this were the problem, however, the error message that the OP sees should include something  about a `bad interpreter`.